# Chart js: How to change value for Y Axis?

Tags: jquery, graph, chart.js2

[image: adding temperature to the y axis]

How can I add °C to the Y Axis in Chart.js v2? The values are generated automatically by the Chart.js library.

This is my code:

```
        var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Temperature'
                    }
                }]
            },

            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Weather Graph'
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to change the y-axis labels on your chart you can add this:

```
...
yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        beginAtZero:false
    },
    scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Temperature'
    },
    afterTickToLabelConversion : function(q){
        for(var tick in q.ticks){
            q.ticks[tick] += '\u00B0C';
        }
    }
}]
...
```

In this function, **afterTickToLabelConversion**, you can alter the labels on the y-axis in the chart.js. They are called ticks :http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRAzmN

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you